Unexpected token error with Invoke-Expression in Powershell
I need to repeat the same command many times while replacing a string by another one from an array. The command has a number of option indicated by "-". When invoking the command Powershell drops the following error:
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:77
+ ... XXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXXX\XXX\XXX\PG_epos_backup" -study_name NE ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-study' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:83
+ ... \XXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXXX\XXX\XXX\PG_epos_backup" -study_name NEXT_ST ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
Unexpected token '_name' in expression or statement.
At X:\XXXXXXXXX\powershell_loop_studies.ps1:11 char:3
+   Invoke-Expression $command
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand`

Thats my Powershell script:
$studies = "0_12007393_13374", "0_12007393_13374_BD", "0_12018871_13400"
$command = '"C:\Program Files\XXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXXX\XXX\XXX\PG_epos_backup" -study_name NEXT_STUDY_NAME -pns_host XXXXXXXXXXXX -out_dir X:\backups_24-10-18 -log_dir X:\backups_24-10-19\00_LOGS -tmp_dir X:\XXXXXXXX\TEMP -stdout'

foreach ($study in $studies)
{
  $command.replace('NEXT_STUDY_NAME',$study)
  Invoke-Expression $command
}


On a separate note, think about if you replace the string NEXT_STUDY_NAME in the first loop, why do you expect to find that value in the second loop?

As for the errors, they are coming from your application PG_epos_backup, which we know nothing about. Do you, perhaps, means --study_name? Tokens can't have underscores (_). I suggest checking the application's documentation.

See also: Rule request: Prefix parameters with an unambiguous (ASCII) hyphen-minus #1932

First thanks for commenting! I realized, the problem is the call of the PG_epos_backup script. I'm a Powershell newbe.
Unlike in CMD terminal, I had to call the backup script using its full name and the executing prefix:: .\PG_epos_backup.cmd.
Although the call works, the intended loop to adjust the option -study_name NEXT_STUDY_NAME doesn't.
As a workaround, I created a script containing all backup commands, which Powershell executes line by line:
.\PG_epos_backup.cmd -study_name 0_12018871_13400 -pns_host XXXXXXXXXXXX -out_dir B:\backups -log_dir B:\backups\00_LOGS -tmp_dir E:\TEMP
